# SpamAssassin: UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67

Tags: centos, perl, cpan, spamassassin

When my Spam Assassin cron job runs, it gives Perl error messages which are then emailed to me by the cron daemon. How can I fix this error or warning?

Cron job: `/usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/sa-update.log`

```
UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
```

I have the latest Perl from CentOS 6 Yum packages, 5.10.1. My Mail::SpamAssassin is up to date (3.004004).